# Adding a launch screen storyboard changes 1st screen collectionView layout

Tags: ios

I am trying to convert from a static launch image to a launch storyboard. When I add the launch storyboard in its default state the collectionView in my first viewController is formatted wrong. I have tried everything I can think of to fix this with no success. Help!

The static image is of the screen below without the collection view items. The Launch Storyboard I am adding is just the launch storyboard file added with no changes.

Without launch Storyboard - the way the collectionView should format:

[image: Without launch Storyboard:]

With launch Storyboard:

[image: With launch Storyboard:]

Comment: both of the screenshots are in different resolutions. First one seems like smaller screen where your collectionview is working perfectly.

Comment: Are the image sizes and collection view settings appropriate?

Comment: You are right about the screen resolution changing as well. This is the same simulator and everything else is the same except for adding the lung storyboard.

Comment: I have been working with the collectionView layout and getting close to replicating the original layout but don't understand how the storyboard would effect this.